# How to use Firebase cloud messaging for a Firestore hosted chat feature alerting users that another user has messaged them?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-extensions

I think the answer is no! But I may be wrong, please clarify my thinking. Here's my journey...

Google's docs suggest Firebase cloud messaging is to be used primarily for marketing purposes, driving engagement, and potentially, for topic subscription.

*AHA!* I thought, that's more like it. I have collections where conversations between users are stored. The collection title is a hash on the User's FirebaseId and the correspondent's FirebaseId, like this:

```
BGIaq55XIB3BPVFAIChC-dQSDAowxT72wXX2nx07x
```

I could have the user subscribe to those collections.

But then I thought, *WAIT!*
What if there's a limit on the number of topics you can subscribe to?

This is where it gets confusing

1. You're allowed 2000 topic subscriptions for each app instance. I presume that's an App instance in Firebase console, not each user gets 2000 topics to follow for their app download.
2. To protect Firebase's service, you won't be allowed to subscribe to many topics in quick succession. => So if my Chat app user received several messages from different people and I tried to follow all those collections, some subscriptions, the later ones, could be refused. Thus the user receives an unreliable notification service.

It would seem Firebase is simply not ideal for delivering alerts in a Whatsapp style, that the user has a new message.

So I'm left wondering how to best alert the user, using Firebase, that they have mail, *not from me*, but from another user.

I could have a single Firestore 'mail' collection, where I list all the users with mail, the user is subscribed to that 'topic', and processes ALL the entries looking for it's the User's firebaseId. But that would mean processing every message for every user of the app, most being not relevant to the user. Probably not viable.

I have built out a chat screen in my app, for in app chat, it took me a long time and I'm a bit astonished that this functionality isn't there. Planning...

**If not Firebase cloud messaging what could I use to prompt users to respond to a Firestore message from a fellow user?**

I suppose an alternative would be using one of Firebase's extensions. Building that global "You've got mail" firebase collection, then once a day, the extension processes the whole collection dispatching emails to users.

Please give me a starting point for how to figure out user-to-user messaging notification. A Medium article, Google docs, a code lab... most welcomed.

Comment: [You should not *force* a tag into your title.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) Because the tags appear below the question and tags are indexed by search engines along with the content of your question, you can trust that other people will be able to find your question based on tags they follow or search for.